# Is there a more efficient way to call multiple apis using graphql and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, graphql, fetch

I am using GraphQL and react on my client side project but I am not using a state management system like Redux

I have organised my api calls into custom hook files like below

```
  const [getSomeData, { data: getSomeDataData, loading: getSomeDataLoading, error: getSomeDataError }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_SOME_DATA2,
    {
      client: dataClient,
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
      nextFetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    }
  );
  return {
    getSomeData,
    getSomeDataData,
    getSomeDataLoading,
    getSomeDataError,
  };
}

export default function useGetSomeData() {
  const [getSomeData2, { data: getSomeData2, loading: getSomeDataLoading2, error: getSomeDataError2 }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_SOME_DATA,
    {
      client: dataClient,
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
      nextFetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    }
  );
  return {
    getSomeData2,
    getSomeDataData2,
    getSomeDataLoading2,
    getSomeDataError2,
  };
}
```

when importing my data to the component im finding myself using a lot of useEffects in order to keep the api calls / state updated like so

```
useEffect(()=>{
getSomeData({
variables})
},[])
useEffect(()=>{
getSomeData2({
variables})
},[])

 useEffect(()=>{

if( getSomeDataData2 && !getSomeDataLoading2 && !getSomeDataError2){
setState(getSomeDataData2?.data)
}
},[getSomeDataData2 ,getSomeDataLoading2 ,getSomeDataError2])

useEffect(()=>{

if( getSomeDataData && !getSomeDataLoading && !getSomeDataError){
setState(getSomeDataData2?.data)
}
},[getSomeDataData ,getSomeDataLoading ,getSomeDataError])
```

i think im over using use effects and i want to limit the number of rerenders per component

does pulling each use effect into its own function and then calling each function in the one useEffect a better practice

```
getSomeData2({
variables})
}

const fetchData2 = () => {
getSomeData2({
variables})
}

useEffect(()=>{
fetchData()
fetchData2()
},[])

 useEffect(()=>{

if( getSomeDataData2 && !getSomeDataLoading2 && !getSomeDataError2){
setState(getSomeDataData2?.data)
}
},[getSomeDataData2 ,getSomeDataLoading2 ,getSomeDataError2])

useEffect(()=>{

if( getSomeDataData && !getSomeDataLoading && !getSomeDataError){
setState(getSomeDataData2?.data)
}
},[getSomeDataData ,getSomeDataLoading ,getSomeDataError])
```

Comment: `useLazyQuery` - is that Apollo client?

Comment: "*i think im over using use effects*" - yes. "*does pulling each use effect into its own function and then calling each function in the one useEffect a better practice*" - no. Instead, you just [should not use an effect at all](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)!

Answer (score 2):

1. The data returned from the Apollo client *is state*. You'll *rarely* need another state management approach.
2. There is no benefit to wrapping `useQuery` in `useEffect`
3. One GraphQL request can run multiple *queries*, example:

```
query myQuery($arg1: String!, $arg2: String!, $arg3: Int!) {
  query1(arg1: $arg1) {
    field11
    field12
  }
  query2(arg2: $arg2, arg3: $arg3){
    field21
    field22
  }
}
```

4. `useLazyQuery` is typically used when a user interface action triggers the query but the data from that query is *not* loaded when the component is mounted
5. `useQuery` is typically used when the component needs to load data when mounted
6. `useState` is typically used to hold values that the user modifies interactively and then these state values are used as variables in GraphQL queries
7. The `refetch` output of a query can be triggered by user action to rerun a query. This function allows for different variables and/or caching strategies to be used during the refetch.